# with use of data type and strings

Tags: android, kotlin

I get the following error:

e: C:\Users\Eric.Almendras\Desktop\project-flutter\scann\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\darryncampbell\datawedgeflutter\MainActivity.kt: (79, 44): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

e: C:\Users\Eric.Almendras\Desktop\project-flutter\scann\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\darryncampbell\datawedgeflutter\MainActivity.kt: (79, 54): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

I can't solve it.. my code is the following:

```
MainActivity.kt

package com.darryncampbell.datawedgeflutter

import android.content.*
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel.EventSink
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel.StreamHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val COMMAND_CHANNEL = "com.darryncampbell.datawedgeflutter/command"
    private val SCAN_CHANNEL = "com.darryncampbell.datawedgeflutter/scan"
    private val PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION = "com.darryncampbell.datawedgeflutter.SCAN"
    private val PROFILE_INTENT_BROADCAST = "2"

    private val dwInterface = DWInterface()

override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor, SCAN_CHANNEL).setStreamHandler(
            object : StreamHandler {
                private var dataWedgeBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
                override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventSink?) {
                    dataWedgeBroadcastReceiver = createDataWedgeBroadcastReceiver(events)
                    val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
                    intentFilter.addAction(PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION)
                    intentFilter.addAction(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_RETURN_ACTION)
                    intentFilter.addCategory(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_RETURN_CATEGORY)
                    registerReceiver(
                            dataWedgeBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
                }

                override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
                    unregisterReceiver(dataWedgeBroadcastReceiver)
                    dataWedgeBroadcastReceiver = null
                }
            }
    )

    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor, COMMAND_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, 
    result ->
        if (call.method == "sendDataWedgeCommandStringParameter")
        {
            val arguments = JSONObject(call.arguments.toString())
            val command: String = arguments.get("command") as String
            val parameter: String = arguments.get("parameter") as String
            dwInterface.sendCommandString(applicationContext, command, parameter)
            //  result.success(0);  //  DataWedge does not return responses
        }
        else if (call.method == "createDataWedgeProfile")
        {
            createDataWedgeProfile(call.arguments.toString())
        }
        else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}

private fun createDataWedgeBroadcastReceiver(events: EventSink?): BroadcastReceiver? {
    return object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action.equals(PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION))
            {
                //  A barcode has been scanned
                var scanData = 
            intent.getStringExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_DATA_STRING)
                var symbology = 
            intent.getStringExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_LABEL_TYPE)
                var date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
                var df = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                var dateTimeString = df.format(date)
                var currentScan = Scan(scanData, symbology, dateTimeString);
                events?.success(currentScan.toJson())
            }
            //  Could handle return values from DW here such as RETURN_GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE
            //  or RETURN_ENUMERATE_SCANNERS
        }
    }
}

private fun createDataWedgeProfile(profileName: String) {
    //  Create and configure the DataWedge profile associated with this application
    //  For readability's sake, I have not defined each of the keys in the DWInterface file
    dwInterface.sendCommandString(this, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_CREATE_PROFILE, 
    profileName)
    val profileConfig = Bundle()
    profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_NAME", profileName)
    profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true") //  These are all strings
    profileConfig.putString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE")
    val barcodeConfig = Bundle()
    barcodeConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE")
    barcodeConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true") //  This is the default but never hurts to 
    specify
    val barcodeProps = Bundle()
    barcodeConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", barcodeProps)
    profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", barcodeConfig)
    val appConfig = Bundle()
    appConfig.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", packageName)      //  Associate the profile with this 
    app
    appConfig.putStringArray("ACTIVITY_LIST", arrayOf("*"))
    profileConfig.putParcelableArray("APP_LIST", arrayOf(appConfig))
    dwInterface.sendCommandBundle(this, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig)
    
    profileConfig.remove("PLUGIN_CONFIG")
    val intentConfig = Bundle()
    intentConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "INTENT")
    intentConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    val intentProps = Bundle()
    intentProps.putString("intent_output_enabled", "true")
    intentProps.putString("intent_action", PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION)
    intentProps.putString("intent_delivery", PROFILE_INTENT_BROADCAST)  //  "2"
    intentConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", intentProps)
    profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", intentConfig)
    dwInterface.sendCommandBundle(this, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig)
  }
}
```

Scan.kt

```
package com.darryncampbell.datawedgeflutter

import org.json.JSONObject;

class Scan(val data: String, val symbology: String, val dateTime: String)
{
    fun toJson(): String{
        return JSONObject(mapOf(
            "scanData" to this.data,
            "symbology" to this.symbology,
            "dateTime" to this.dateTime
        )).toString();
    }
}
```

can someone see my mistake?

Comment: Please tell us which if line 79 of your code where the issue happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kotlin is designed in a null safe matter. `String?` basically means, a `String` that can possibly be null. So kotlin disallows assigning `String?` where it expects `String`.

Your error says exactly where it happens.
`MainActivity.kt: (79, 44)` in your log means it's on line 79 of your code.

I'm guessing it's the line

```
var currentScan = Scan(scanData, symbology, dateTimeString);
```

`scanData` and `symbology` are of type `String?` but `Scan` requires `String` there. One easy way to convert it is to write it as

```
var currentScan = Scan(scanData!!, symbology!!, dateTimeString);
```

With `!!` you basically say, "I'm sure this is not null". The code will crash though if it does happen to be `null`

Answer (score 0):

This is related to null safety in Kotlin. Your are inferring string as nullable , but where it is being used, it is expecting it as non nullable string. You can check for null before using it or have a mechanism to check null values and handle it.

[Check this link for more detailed description for nullable variables](https://medium.com/@sumit.ingewar/kotlin-basic-fundamentals-part-2-90e1e5baee0)